# double converted to hours minutes and seconds with NSdateformatter returning wrong answer

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

i am using the following code to convert a value of 18900 into hh:mm:ss

unfortunately the value returned doesn't seem right as it gives me 06:15:00

can anyone please advise why its going wrong

thanks

```
-(NSString*)setHours:(double)result
{

NSLog(@"result %0.2f",result);
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:result];
                NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
                 NSString *localizedString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
                [formatter release];
                return localizedString;

}
```

Comment: I believe it's seconds since Jan 1, 1970. So you're getting the time 18900s since then.

Comment: What does 18900 mean? is it from 1970 or unix time stamp or only number of seconds?

Comment: What is the value you are expecting? Also what value are you passing in for "result" that is giving you 06:15:00?

Comment: 18900 is a double value representing seconds so i'm expecting 5 hours and 15 minutes

Comment: int secs = result;
    int h = secs / 3600;
    int m = secs / 60 % 60;
    int s = secs % 60;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a value that is the number of seconds since midnight, you don't need a date formatter. Try this:

```
-(NSString*)setHours:(double)result {
    int secs = result;
    int h = secs / 3600;
    int m = secs / 60 % 60;
    int s = secs % 60;

    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s];
}
```

Comment: thanks everyone for your answers but i've chosen to change my method to this as its simple and works a treat

Answer (score 2):

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to convert miliseconds in to seconds by dividing miliseconds by 1000.

```
   NSTimeInterval result= 18900/1000;
   NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:result];
   NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
   NSString *formattedDate=[formatter stringFromDate:date];
   NSLog(@"Formatted Date : %@",formattedDate);
```

Comment: I don't think he is passing milliseconds. I think he expected 5:15 instead of 6:15.

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you a result for your current time zone, and the time is specified in UTC. So you're an hour after GMT I suppose.

Check out this question: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 NOT returning GMT/UTC time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068104/nsdate-datewithtimeintervalsince1970-not-returning-gmt-utc-time)